# What does "Connectors with shared bandwidth" mean on a motherboard?

Tags: motherboard, sata, pci-express, m.2

I have a z590-E with the following in the manual...

[image]

The problem is there is no context given to the "configurations" and I am not sure what it is trying to tell me. I seem to not be able to get m.2_2 working when I have PCIEX16_1, PCIEX16_2, PCIEX16_3 and SATA6G_1 filled.

Answer (score 0):

It does have to do with number of devices (even though the first one says 3 when there is in fact 4). In my case m.2_2 was not showing up thanks to a bios setting. Once I changed it, everything worked.

[image]